# Problem with centering the text of the title page and more

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, titles

The following is the code related to my title page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[algoruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}

% for nice tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
% end for nice tables

% for using color names
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
% end for using color names

% for nicer figure captions
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
% end for nicer figure captions


% fancy headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for upper line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for lower line
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{colortbl}

% for multirow option in the tables
\usepackage{multirow}



\usepackage[semicolon]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\newenvironment{myfancybox}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{black}}%
  \color{black}\MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}





%\bibliographystyle{plain} %Choose a bibliograhpic style

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\itshape}

% for height of the heading 
 \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\parskip1ex
\begin{document}

 \begin{titlepage}
 \quad
  \vspace{2cm}
 \quad
 \begin{center}
 {\fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont \textbf{
  Word1\\
  %\vspace{2mm}
  Word Word\\
  \vspace{2mm}
  Word Word Word}
 }

 {\large text text text text
     text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text}  


\end{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that my title has 'Word 1' quite separated from the second row. Another problem is that the whole text is actually not centered. I my preview it is shifted to the left. How could I adjust the title page to have proper title and with the centered text? My intention is to have the title page close to this: http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/documents/DementievDiss.pdf
I would appreciate help on how to achieve such a title page.

Comment: Please, make the code snippet into a MWE: without knowing the class you're using it's difficult to give a sensible answer.

Comment: @egreg I edited my question. Please write a comment on how to easily copy/paste the code from my .tex file such that it is display as with 4 white spaces at this website.

Comment: Please use a more describing title. "Problem with title page" can fit 100 different questions.

Comment: @MartinScharrer  Well, any question can fit 100 questions.

Comment: @boy: Not on tex.sx `;)` -- a question here should be exactly one problem, one distinct issue. This way, the posts are supposed to be maximally helpful for other users looking for help. That's why we require a certain degree of abstraction in questions.

Comment: regarding why there is more space after "word 1", you have wrapped that block in a group, so the baselines will revert to the "outside" value when the group closes unless the group ends with a blank line or `\par`.  the baselineskip appropriate for the type size inside the group will be applied between the first and second lines since the second line ends with `\\` forcing the setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to do it with standard LaTeX commands, so some low level TeX can come handy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\hrule height0pt % fix a starting point
\vskip 0pt minus 1000pt % back up how much it's needed

\raggedright % no indentation

\hspace*{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - \oddsidemargin - 1in - \hoffset\relax}% shift to center
\hbox to 0pt{% make a zero width box
\vbox to \textheight{\centering % this is the main part
%%%
\vspace*{\fill}
\hrule
\vspace{1.5cm}

\textsc{Brutus C. Dull}

\vspace{1.5cm}

{\Large\bfseries Applied Tetrapiloctomy\\
for GPS Systems\par}

\vspace{1cm}

\hrule

\vspace{\stretch{5}}

\parbox{2.5cm}{
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-1x1}}}
\hfill
\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-3.5cm\relax}{
\raggedright\large\sffamily Dissertation zur Erlangung des Grades
des Doktors der Ingenieurwissenschaften (Dr.-Ing.)
der Naturwissenschaftlich-Technischen Fakult\"aten
der Universit\"at des Saarlandes\par
\medskip
\hrule
\medskip
\hspace*{\fill}Saarbr\"ucken, 2006\par
}\par
}%end of \vbox
\hss}%end of \hbox

\vskip 0pt minus 1000pt % some space for accommodating the whole thing
\hrule height0pt % fix an end point
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```